# How to find the number of solutions of $3^x + 4^x + 5 ^x = 6^x$

Tags: graphing-functions

My try:

I tried plotting the graph(manually) of LHS and RHS but it does not give any information whether they will intersect or not.If they will intersect then there will be 1 solution and if they do not intersect then there will be no solution. But the main problem I found was to check if they intersect or not.

Please do not use the aid of Wolfram Alpha, graphing calculator while answering this question.

Comment: check slopes???

Comment: Sorry but use of derivatives is not allowed.

Comment: Take 3^x to that side? Maybe.

Comment: @Awesome Taking $3^x$ to the other side doesn't help.

Comment: @rah4927 there are finite number of solutions.

Comment: That shows you that there are no negative solutions

Comment: Since you already know that there is at most one solution, check $x=0$ and $x=4$...

Comment: @user2369284,yes there(probably) are a finite number of solutions.I (as usual) misread the question.

Comment: 3­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: It's a fairly well known fact that $3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 = 6^3$ but anyway, generally: there's a zero if a continuous function switches from positive to negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide both sides by $6^x$:
$$\tag1\left(\frac12\right)^x+\left(\frac23\right)^x+\left(\frac56\right)^x=1.$$
Note that $f(x)=q^x$ with $0<q<1$ has the property that $f(0)=1$, $f$ is continuous and strictly decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ and $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. Therefore the left hand side in $(1)$ is $3$ at $x=0$, is continuous and structliy decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ and converges to $0$ as $x\to\infty$. By the IVT, there exists at least one $x$ and by monotonicity at most one $x$ such that the LHS equals $1$.

Comment: Great answer!!!

Comment: More over, since $\left(\frac12\right)^3+\left(\frac23\right)^3+\left(\frac56\right)^3=1$, we can state there are no solutions $>3$...and since $f(x) = \left(\frac12\right)^3+\left(\frac23\right)^3+\left(\frac56\right)^3$ is striclty decreasing on $[0,+\infty)$, there are no solutions $<3$. So there is only one solution ($x=3$).